# R: How to read in tab-delimited data whilst ignoring odd characters?

Tags: r, fread

I have a load of files in sub-directories all with the same format, which I would like to import and concatenate with an idcolumn belonging to then directory+filename they came from:

```
(bed 12)
(          x           y            z            u            v            w     diameter            t    mass-flow         mass    frequency         time         name)
(( 3.3109e+00   1.9791e+00   9.8968e-01   3.8232e-03  -2.3234e-03  -4.7283e-03   4.2372e-07   3.0000e+02   1.9023e-13   3.9759e-17   4.7844e+03   3.5049e+01) injection-0:426)
(( 3.2420e+00   1.9782e+00   9.3270e-01  -1.5477e-04   4.0080e-04  -2.3946e-04   9.0324e-07   3.0000e+02   1.2563e-12   3.8514e-16   3.2620e+03   3.2168e+02) injection-0:1147)
(( 3.1500e+00   1.9731e+00   8.5654e-01  -1.7934e-04   1.0918e-03  -8.8252e-04   2.1000e-06   3.0000e+02   9.4751e-12   4.8406e-15   1.9574e+03   1.6171e+02) injection-0:2943)
```

Theoretically it's not too hard and vroom is my go-to but it can't guess then delimiter and imports three columns, one of which is all the numbers as one big character vector:

```
files<-list.files("*.dpm",recursive=TRUE)
df<-vroom::vroom(files,id="path", skip=1)%>%janitor::clean_names()
```

1. I think I can write the third column to disk then re-read it using `read.table` but this is a faff.
2. Split the third column using `stringr::str_split()` but not ideal either.
3. Use `awk` to remove all the ( and ) from all the files. I'd have to eventually ask a stack question for this method I think anyway.

Any thoughts please?

**EDIT:**

The following code seems to work:

```
df <-data.table::rbindlist(
  sapply(files, data.table::fread, skip=1, fill=TRUE, simplify = FALSE),
  use.names = TRUE, idcol = "FileName")
```

but I prefer vroom's one-liner. Any other solutions?

Comment: Apologies if I'm misunderstanding your question (and don't have the data to reproduce the issue of course), but can you pass `vroom` the `delim = "\t"` argument to force it to read as tab delimited instead of guessing the delimiter?

Comment: That causes R to crash unfortunately. I have seen that with vroom when it tries to open too many files.

Comment: Hm, another thought would be a wrapper around `read_tsv` but it's not much different than the `data.table` option. Not sure there's much other choice, at least that I'm aware of. 
`df <- bind_rows(lapply(files, function(x) cbind(read_tsv(x, skip = 1), id = x)))`